# Should I approach my boss about changing my job title since the type of work I do is different now?

Tags: title

I am an intern at a small company (I do get paid). I got hired as a Client Account Executive and at the start of my internship I was doing what this job title encompasses. However, after about a week and a chat with my boss I started programming a piece of software for them (nothing amazing, just a little program that handles their customer data better). This now consumes most of my weekly duties. Every now and then I still handle some other tasks that would fall into the CAE category but they don't take long to do.

Should I approach my boss before the internship ends and ask him if I can state that I worked as Software Developer instead of a CAE on my CV? The reason I am asking is because the SD title would benefit me more in the future as I am planning into going to a programming based career.

Comment: Why not approach him right now?

Comment: That's what I meant. The internship ends in about 2 weeks so as long as I do it before then I will be happy.

Comment: Do interns need titles or are you just going to indicate the type of work you did?

Comment: I just want something that reflects the type of work I have done better on my CV/Resume

Comment: possible duplicate of [My job duties do not match the job title/description. How do I approach my boss about changing this?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18180/my-job-duties-do-not-match-the-job-title-description-how-do-i-approach-my-boss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is very innocent, approach him right away and ask him if your title can be changed so that it describes better what you've been doing for the company.

The worst thing that can happen is that he says no, at least you asked.

It's more likely, though, that your request will be accepted.

It (almost) never hurts to ask.

**Edit:**

Yes, the biggest part of your time was spent on developing software, that makes you a software developer.

You could approach him with something like

> I was hired to do tasks A, B, C, ... but over X% of my time has been spent on task D (developing software). Would it be okay if my title would be changed, accordingly, to *Software Developer*, to reflect better the actual work that I'm doing for the company?

If he says that it's too much of an effort to change the title within the company, at least you can get his permission to say *Software Developer* on your resume, just don't forget to mention on your resume that Software Development was not the only thing you were doing. I hope this helps.

Comment: I've noticed you're a software-developer, maybe you could help me further. The reason I am hesitant is that I don't know whether what I've done is enough to classify me as one. I have made a GUI of a custom database handler; it handles their data, does sorting, adding, removing, editing, exporting etc... I have about 1000 lines of code so far and I have made the whole thing redistributable (so into an .exe file that works anywhere). Is this enough to class me a software developer?

Comment: I tried to edit my answer accordingly.