# Should I confront again my boss about my wrong job title?

Tags: title

What I originally applied for is a digital marketing position. Through my first week there, it's more of a sales position which I didn't like so I told my boss I don't like my job and would like to be transferred to a different department. Which he did and I have a completely different job now where I do graphic design.

But on our realignment meeting, I asked what my title is and he said "marketing account executive." It's because that's what I originally applied for and that was in my contract (which there wasn't really a signed formal contract).

Although when you think about it, I'm kind of in the marketing side since I do the graphics for ads.

But my question is, do I have the right to still talk about it to him and force him to change my title? That's going to be confusing on my CV. I do a different job on my title.

Comment: Is a job title that important to you?

Comment: If you go to your boss intending to 'confront' him instead of 'discuss' with him, you've already lost even if he ultimately agrees to what you want.

Comment: "Confront" would be the wrong word. Obviously you would ask him to change your job title, if the job title doesn't describe what you are actually doing, but there should be no need for a confrontation. In your CV, you list what you have done, translating it into some matching job title if needed.

Comment: "that's what I originally applied for and that was in my contract (which there wasn't really a signed formal contract)" - these two things seem contradictory. Did you originally agree to the "marketing account executive" title when you accepted the job?

Answer (score 7):

Some of the language you use makes me question how you approach your job. You apparently didn't do your due diligence when interviewing for this position and had no clue about the role you'd start in. You then asked (demanded?) to be transferred, which they did(!). And now you want to "force" through a title change?

In a typical employer-employee or manager-report relationship, you don't have the right to force anything. You can certainly build a case for why your title should be updated to reflect your new position as it would confuse colleagues or clients. More details are here: [My job duties do not match the job title/description. How do I approach my boss about changing this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18180/my-job-duties-do-not-match-the-job-title-description-how-do-i-approach-my-boss?lq=1)

But if your title is actually updated to reflect your new department, then that just means that this company has standardised vague titles and there's nothing to be done about that. On your resume you'd typically list your actual role next to the official position. See the advice here: [How to label inaccurate job titles on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13494/how-to-label-inaccurate-job-titles-on-resume)

Comment: For some reason, i cant reply to the answers and its not the user i loggrd in when i asked this question. This is a reply for @lilienthal: Well on my interview, the job discussed to me was a technical job since i am in IT. So data analytics and even web dev. But when i was there, in sourcing for clients, doing presentations, basically selling! So i asked to be tranferred which im glad that my boss was ok with it.

Comment: Also not a great idea to be demanding and forcing anything when you basically just walked in the door and should be working on creating a 'good' impression.