# Job description didn't match job duties?

Tags: new-job, job-description

I took a position couple of months ago thinking it was an IT job (as was described in the job posting description) It stated it was in IT department and listed all the basic things IT jobs do. Networking, programming, databases etc..

So I accepted the role and it turned out to be a customer service position and did not match the description that was listed in their job posting. What should I do? Confront them that the job is not what was advertised?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My job duties do not match the job title/description. How do I approach my boss about changing this?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18180/my-job-duties-do-not-match-the-job-title-description-how-do-i-approach-my-boss)

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do? Confront them that the job is not what was
>   advertised?

- Determine what kind of work you really want to do.
- Talk to your boss, asking about your current role compared to your desired role.
- If you don't see a path that takes you to your desired role in a reasonable
  period of time, start looking elsewhere.
- Find a new job with a role that you desire
- Quit your current job, giving an appropriate notice period
- Start your new job and new role

You may also want to ponder for a few minutes why your current role turned out differently than expected. Consider if there were questions you should have asked that would have made it more obvious that this wasn't what you desired. Think about how you will handle it differently in the future (ask different questions, ask potential peers and not just one interviewer, etc.)